# Get integer after a character from file

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read the number of a txt file like this:

```
input=20
output=10
hidden=5
....
```

I tried with this code:

```
char line[30];
char values[100][20];
int i = 0;
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("cannot open file\n");
    return 0;
}
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
{
     sscanf(line, "%[^=]", values[i])
        printf("%s\n", values[i]);

    i++;
}
fclose(fp);
```

But I obtain only the first word and never the number after the `=`.

I get

```
input
output
etc
```

instead of

```
20
10
5
etc
```

How can I get the number??

Comment: @ryyker , Why? `sizeof(line)/sizeof(line[0])==sizeof(line)` because `sizeof(char)==sizeof(line[0])==1`

Comment: Yes why? `sizeof(line[0]) == 1` obviously, so why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
sscanf(line, "%[^=]", values[i]);
```

means "read everything up to, but not including, the `=` sign into `values[i]`".

If you are interested in the numeric part *after* the equal sign, change the call as follows:

```
sscanf(line, "%*[^=]=%19s", values[i]);
```

This format line means "read and ignore (because of the asterisk) everything up to, and including, the equal sign. Then read a string of length of up to 19 characters into `values[i]`".

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WJH4NY)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sscanf()` for that, redeclare `values` to store the integers like

```
int values[LARGE_CONSTANT_NUMBER];
```

and after `fgets()` just use `strchr`

```
char *number;

number = strchr(line, '=');
if (number == NULL)
    continue;
number   += 1;
values[i] = strtol(number, NULL, 10);
```

you could also use `malloc()` and `realloc()` if you wish, to make the `values` array dynamic.

Try it if you like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char   line[100];
    int    values[100];
    int    i;
    FILE  *fp;
    size_t maxIntegers;

    fp = fopen("myFile.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("cannot open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    i           = 0;
    maxIntegers = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);
    while ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) && (i < maxIntegers))
    {
        char *number;

        number = strchr(line, '=');
        if (number == NULL) /* this line does not contain a `=' */
            continue;
        values[i++] = strtol(number + 1, NULL, 10);

        printf("%d\n", values[i - 1]);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

with this technique you avoid unecessarily storing the number as a string.